# VLC udp stream stops after any interrupt or track change in lan in mac os

Tags: networking, audio, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I am trying to stream audio in lan network in mac os sierra with vlc version 2.2.5.1 Umbrella.

I am able to stream my playlist .xspf file. But it stops after one song finish or track change and need to reconnect again in client machine (receiver). I am using default vlc wizard to stream setup.

I tried sout keep , sout all and gather. Also i tried to encode all songs in same format by selecting trancode audio.But nothing worked for me.Perhaps i am trying commands in wrong order.It works fine for windows 7 os.Please guide me in this what's going wrong?

Below are MRL generating by vlc wizard.

[image]

here is what i am receving log in receiver machine,

```
     /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/share/lua/meta/art
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for aa
macosx debug: releasing old sleep blocker (34696)
macosx debug: prevented sleep through IOKit (34702)
ts debug: PMTCallBack called
ts debug: new PMT program number=1 version=2 pid_pcr=68
ts debug:   * es pid=68 type=3 dr->i_tag=0xa
ts debug: found language: 
ts debug:   * es pid=68 type=3 fcc=mpga
ts warning: discontinuity received 0x0 instead of 0x9 (pid=68)
core warning: clock gap, unexpected stream discontinuity
core warning: feeding synchro with a new reference point trying to recover from clock gap
core debug: discarded audio buffer
mpeg_audio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core warning: clock gap, unexpected stream discontinuity
core warning: feeding synchro with a new reference point trying to recover from clock gap
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337150977
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337177099
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337203222
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337229344
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337255466
core debug: discarded audio buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your log

Namely:
`core warning: clock gap, unexpected stream discontinuity
core warning: feeding synchro with a new reference point trying to recover from clock gap
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)`

It looks like you have time conversion issue.  My guess is that there is a date format issue or some kind of overflow within the VLC (hard to tell without proper debugging or seeing the values)

The error appears to be (https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/694399e23000232708b2d514a6a265cfc023ddde/src/input/clock.c from the source code):

> /* Stream discontinuity, for which we haven't received a
>            * warning from the stream control facilities (dd-edited
>            * stream ?). */

There is a gap definition:

```
/* Maximum gap allowed between two CRs. */
#define CR_MAX_GAP (60 * CLOCK_FREQ)
```

The clock frequency is defined as:

```
/* All timestamp below or equal to this define are invalid/unset
 * XXX the numerical value is 0 because of historical reason and will change.*/
#define VLC_TS_INVALID INT64_C(0)
#define VLC_TS_0 INT64_C(1)

#define CLOCK_FREQ INT64_C(1000000)
```

There are similar two tickets on the matter on VLC ticketing system (without any solution): 
[First ticket](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/17687)
[Second ticket](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/18175)

My recommendation is to upgrade VLC player to latest 2.2.6 to see if this bug was fixed. (https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5758/vlc-media-player).
  Other than that file a bug report at VLC trac.videolan.org with proper logs attached.

Comment: i updated vlc to  2.2.6 but it didn't help, getting same error. Is there any other easy way to stream audio in lan in mac os ?

Comment: @HarshalBhatt: well if you still get the same error you can try the Eltima player - https://mac.eltima.com/elmedia-player-download.html.  The functionality you are seeking is free.  Some other functionality like AirPlay is only in the PRO version which you have to buy.

Comment: @tuskan thanks for the other suggestion. i'll try that player.

Comment: @HarshalBhatt: Please do, if you find that this works please accept my answer.  Thank you.